# How to replace various characters in a variable in dataframe using R?

Tags: r

I try to convert a varialbe "value" in the problem to that in the result.

Is there any easy way to do?

```r
problem <- data.frame(tic = c("AAL"), value = c("250M", "120K", "10B"))
```

```r
result <- data.frame(tic = c("AAL"), value = c(250000000, 120000, 10000000000))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
problem %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(str_replace_all(value,
     setNames(c("e3", "e6", "e9"), c("K", "M", "B")))))
```

-output

```
  tic       value
1 AAL   250000000
2 AAL      120000
3 AAL 10000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a custom function that defines the shorthands `KMB`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# custom function
my_func <- function(x) {
  to_multiply <- case_when(
    str_ends(x, "K") ~ 1000,
    str_ends(x, "M") ~ 1000000,
    str_ends(x, "B") ~ 1000000000,
    TRUE ~ 1
  )
  
  numeric <- as.numeric(str_remove(x, "[KMB]$"))
  return(numeric * to_multiply)
}

# code
problem %>% 
  mutate(value = format(my_func(value), scientific=FALSE))
```

output:

```
 tic       value
1 AAL   250000000
2 AAL      120000
3 AAL 10000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively,

```
problem %>% mutate(
    value = stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(value, c("K", "M", "B"), c("e3", "e6", "e9"), vectorize_all=FALSE) %>% as.numeric())
```